# How to tell if Lightning nodes are lnd, c-lightning, eclair

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, core-lightning, eclair, lightning-network

I am performing some experiments on the Lightning Testnet Network. I would like to perform the experiment on the 3 main lightning implementations, for which I would like to be able to connect and open a channel with an `lnd`, `c-lightning` and `eclair` node.

- Is there a list of `lnd`, `c-lightning`, `eclair` nodes that are announced? even if just in testnet?
- Is there a way of knowing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of knowing this on a protocol level... What you could do is to set up your own nodes (each node with a certain implementation) or some people say publicly which nodes they run. For example my node is c Lightning, ACINQ is using eclair and I believe rompert is running on lnd.
Also on 1ml.com some owners register their nodes and tell what they are running. Of course they could lie...

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Rene mentioned, no such way to detect type is provided in protocols, but at [1ml.com](https://1ml.com) you can see what type of node is being run.
The data at [1ml](https://1ml.com) is filled by node owners manually so it may be incorrect as well.

For experimenting you need to start all the type of nodes, that would be better option.